# Rails Issue. Object doesn't support valid method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am having an issue with routing my starter web page properly, I have spent over 2 hours trying different things based off guides, the steps I have taken are as follows.

in app``/controllers/pages_controller.rb

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController
def home
end
```

end

moving onto config.routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
```

get 'pages/home'
  root 'pages#home'
end

(I tried this line of code instead get 'welcome' => 'pages#home', but it does not work.)

According to the resources I am using to teach myself rails, I have done everything correct, and yet I cannot figure out how, or **why I am getting the following error in app/views/layouts/application.html.erb where line #5 raised:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>MySite</title>
<%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-  track' => true %>
<%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
<%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
<body>

<%= yield %>

</body>
</html>
```

This is the standard file that is always created when I create a new site with rails.

Can anyone help me to correct this error?

UPDATING POST --- 7/8/2016 12:00 PM PST

Error is as follows

C://...MySite/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb where line #5 raised:

TypeError: Object doesn't support this property or method

> execjs (2.7.0) lib/execjs/external_runtime.rb:39:in `exec'
>   execjs (2.7.0) lib/execjs/external_runtime.rb:21:in`eval'
>   execjs (2.7.0) lib/execjs/external_runtime.rb:46:in `call'
>   coffee-script (2.4.1) lib/coffee_script.rb:78:in`compile'
>   sprockets (3.6.3) lib/sprockets/coffee_script_processor.rb:21:in `block in call'
>   sprockets (3.6.3) lib/sprockets/cache.rb:85:in`fetch'
>   sprockets (3.6.3) lib/sprockets/coffee_script_processor.rb:20:in `call'
>   sprockets (3.6.3) lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:75:in`call_processor'
>   sprockets (3.6.3) lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:57:in `block in call_processors'
>   sprockets (3.6.3) lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:56:in`reverse_each'
>   sprockets (3.6.3) lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:56:in `call_processors'
>   sprockets (3.6.3) lib/sprockets/loader.rb:134:in`load_from_unloaded'
>   sprockets (3.6.3) lib/sprockets/loader.rb:60:in `block in load'
>   sprockets (3.6.3) lib/sprockets/loader.rb:317:in`fetch_asset_from_dependency_cache'
>   sprockets (3.6.3) lib/sprockets/loader.rb:44:in `load'
>   sprockets (3.6.3) lib/sprockets/cached_environment.rb:20:in`block in initialize'
>   sprockets (3.6.3) lib/sprockets/cached_environment.rb:47:in `yield'
>   sprockets (3.6.3) lib/sprockets/cached_environment.rb:47:in`load'
>   sprockets (3.6.3) lib/sprockets/bundle.rb:23:in `block in call'
>   sprockets (3.6.3) lib/sprockets/utils.rb:196:in`dfs'
>   sprockets (3.6.3) lib/sprockets/bundle.rb:24:in `call'
>   sprockets (3.6.3) lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:75:in`call_processor'
>   sprockets (3.6.3) lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:57:in `block in call_processors'
>   sprockets (3.6.3) lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:56:in`reverse_each'
>   sprockets (3.6.3) lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:56:in `call_processors'
>   sprockets (3.6.3) lib/sprockets/loader.rb:134:in`load_from_unloaded'
>   sprockets (3.6.3) lib/sprockets/loader.rb:60:in `block in load'
>   sprockets (3.6.3) lib/sprockets/loader.rb:317:in`fetch_asset_from_dependency_cache'
>   sprockets (3.6.3) lib/sprockets/loader.rb:44:in `load'
>   sprockets (3.6.3) lib/sprockets/cached_environment.rb:20:in`block in initialize'
>   sprockets (3.6.3) lib/sprockets/cached_environment.rb:47:in `yield'
>   sprockets (3.6.3) lib/sprockets/cached_environment.rb:47:in`load'
>   sprockets (3.6.3) lib/sprockets/base.rb:66:in `find_asset'
>   sprockets (3.6.3) lib/sprockets/base.rb:73:in`find_all_linked_assets'
>   sprockets (3.6.3) lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:142:in `block in find'
>   sprockets (3.6.3) lib/sprockets/legacy.rb:114:in`block (2 levels) in logical_paths'
>   sprockets (3.6.3) lib/sprockets/path_utils.rb:228:in `block in stat_tree'
>   sprockets (3.6.3) lib/sprockets/path_utils.rb:212:in`block in stat_directory'
>   sprockets (3.6.3) lib/sprockets/path_utils.rb:209:in `each'
>   sprockets (3.6.3) lib/sprockets/path_utils.rb:209:in`stat_directory'
>   sprockets (3.6.3) lib/sprockets/path_utils.rb:227:in `stat_tree'
>   sprockets (3.6.3) lib/sprockets/legacy.rb:105:in`each'
>   sprockets (3.6.3) lib/sprockets/legacy.rb:105:in `block in logical_paths'
>   sprockets (3.6.3) lib/sprockets/legacy.rb:104:in`each'
>   sprockets (3.6.3) lib/sprockets/legacy.rb:104:in `logical_paths'
>   sprockets (3.6.3) lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:140:in`find'
>   sprockets-rails (3.1.1) lib/sprockets/railtie.rb:50:in `each'
>   sprockets-rails (3.1.1) lib/sprockets/railtie.rb:50:in`map'
>   sprockets-rails (3.1.1) lib/sprockets/railtie.rb:50:in `precompiled_assets'
>   sprockets-rails (3.1.1) lib/sprockets/railtie.rb:35:in`asset_precompiled?'
>   sprockets-rails (3.1.1) lib/sprockets/railtie.rb:250:in `block (3 levels) in <class:Railtie>'
>   sprockets-rails (3.1.1) lib/sprockets/rails/helper.rb:342:in`call'
>   sprockets-rails (3.1.1) lib/sprockets/rails/helper.rb:342:in `precompiled?'
>   sprockets-rails (3.1.1) lib/sprockets/rails/helper.rb:346:in`raise_unless_precompiled_asset'
>   sprockets-rails (3.1.1) lib/sprockets/rails/helper.rb:331:in `find_debug_asset'
>   sprockets-rails (3.1.1) lib/sprockets/rails/helper.rb:212:in`block in lookup_debug_asset'
>   sprockets-rails (3.1.1) lib/sprockets/rails/helper.rb:225:in `block in resolve_asset'
>   sprockets-rails (3.1.1) lib/sprockets/rails/helper.rb:224:in`each'
>   sprockets-rails (3.1.1) lib/sprockets/rails/helper.rb:224:in `detect'
>   sprockets-rails (3.1.1) lib/sprockets/rails/helper.rb:224:in`resolve_asset'
>   sprockets-rails (3.1.1) lib/sprockets/rails/helper.rb:211:in `lookup_debug_asset'
>   sprockets-rails (3.1.1) lib/sprockets/rails/helper.rb:153:in`block in stylesheet_link_tag'
>   sprockets-rails (3.1.1) lib/sprockets/rails/helper.rb:152:in `map'
>   sprockets-rails (3.1.1) lib/sprockets/rails/helper.rb:152:in`stylesheet_link_tag'
>   app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:5:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb___179903429_57233724'
>   actionview (4.2.6) lib/action_view/template.rb:145:in`block in render'
>   activesupport (4.2.6) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:166:in `instrument'
>   actionview (4.2.6) lib/action_view/template.rb:333:in`instrument'
>   actionview (4.2.6) lib/action_view/template.rb:143:in `render'
>   actionview (4.2.6) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:66:in`render_with_layout'
>   actionview (4.2.6) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:52:in `render_template'
>   actionview (4.2.6) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:14:in`render'
>   actionview (4.2.6) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:46:in `render_template'
>   actionview (4.2.6) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:27:in`render'
>   actionview (4.2.6) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:100:in `_render_template'
>   actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_controller/metal/streaming.rb:217:in`_render_template'
>   actionview (4.2.6) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:83:in `render_to_body'
>   actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:32:in`render_to_body'
>   actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_controller/metal/renderers.rb:37:in `render_to_body'
>   actionpack (4.2.6) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:25:in`render'
>   actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:16:in `render'
>   actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:44:in`block (2 levels) in render'
>   activesupport (4.2.6) lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:12:in `block in ms'
>   C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/benchmark.rb:294:in`realtime'
>   activesupport (4.2.6) lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:12:in `ms'
>   actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:44:in`block in render'
>   actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:87:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
>   activerecord (4.2.6) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:25:in`cleanup_view_runtime'
>   actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:43:in `render'
>   actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:10:in`default_render'
>   actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:5:in `send_action'
>   actionpack (4.2.6) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:198:in`process_action'
>   actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
>   actionpack (4.2.6) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:20:in`block in process_action'
>   activesupport (4.2.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:117:in `call'
>   activesupport (4.2.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:117:in`call'
>   activesupport (4.2.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:555:in `block (2 levels) in compile'
>   activesupport (4.2.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:505:in`call'
>   activesupport (4.2.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:505:in `call'
>   activesupport (4.2.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:92:in`**run_callbacks**'
>   activesupport (4.2.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:778:in `_run_process_action_callbacks'
>   activesupport (4.2.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in`run_callbacks'
>   actionpack (4.2.6) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:19:in `process_action'
>   actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in`process_action'
>   actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:32:in `block in process_action'
>   activesupport (4.2.6) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in`block in instrument'
>   activesupport (4.2.6) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
>   activesupport (4.2.6) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in`instrument'
>   actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `process_action'
>   actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:250:in`process_action'
>   activerecord (4.2.6) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
>   actionpack (4.2.6) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:137:in`process'
>   actionview (4.2.6) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:30:in `process'
>   actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:196:in`dispatch'
>   actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:13:in `dispatch'
>   actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:237:in`block in action'
>   actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:74:in `call'
>   actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:74:in`dispatch'
>   actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:43:in `serve'
>   actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:43:in`block in serve'
>   actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:30:in `each'
>   actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:30:in`serve'
>   actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:817:in `call'
>   rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/etag.rb:24:in`call'
>   rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:25:in `call'
>   rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/head.rb:13:in`call'
>   actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:27:in `call'
>   actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:260:in`call'
>   rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:225:in `context'
>   rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:220:in`call'
>   actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:560:in `call'
>   activerecord (4.2.6) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:36:in`call'
>   activerecord (4.2.6) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:653:in `call'
>   activerecord (4.2.6) lib/active_record/migration.rb:377:in`call'
>   actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
>   activesupport (4.2.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:88:in`**run_callbacks**'
>   activesupport (4.2.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:778:in `_run_call_callbacks'
>   activesupport (4.2.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in`run_callbacks'
>   actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
>   actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:73:in`call'
>   actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:78:in `call'
>   actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in`call'
>   web-console (2.3.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:28:in `block in call'
>   web-console (2.3.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:18:in`catch'
>   web-console (2.3.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:18:in `call'
>   actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in`call'
>   railties (4.2.6) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
>   railties (4.2.6) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in`block in call'
>   activesupport (4.2.6) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
>   activesupport (4.2.6) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in`tagged'
>   activesupport (4.2.6) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
>   railties (4.2.6) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in`call'
>   actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
>   rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:22:in`call'
>   rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/runtime.rb:18:in `call'
>   activesupport (4.2.6) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:28:in`call'
>   rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
>   actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:120:in`call'
>   rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:113:in `call'
>   railties (4.2.6) lib/rails/engine.rb:518:in`call'
>   railties (4.2.6) lib/rails/application.rb:165:in `call'
>   rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in`call'
>   rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/content_length.rb:15:in `call'
>   rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:88:in`service'
>   C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
>   C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in`run'
>   C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/server.rb:295:in `block in

rails version 2.1.0

GemFile

```html
# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.2.6'
# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
gem 'sqlite3'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
# See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
# bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc

# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use Unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug'
end

group :development do
  # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> in views
  gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'
end

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
```

And Finally by platform I do not specifically know what you are referring to?

I am using windows 7 platform on my laptop. But can you clarify what you specifically mean by platform? Thank you very much for requesting that I post this information and I look forward to your responses.

Comment: Can you post the whole error please? Also ruby/rails versions, gemfile, what platform you are developing on.

Answer (score 1):

A trivial error has occurred with your `application.html.erb` file on line #5:
a couple of unintentional spaces (`" "`) in `data-turbolinks-track` key on the `stylesheet_link_tag`. The following code would work!

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>MySite</title>
<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
<%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
<%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
<body>

<%= yield %>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Good eye @wasifhossain bhai :) +1

Answer (score 0):

> Error is as follows
>
> C://...MySite/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb where line #5
>   raised:

So - the error you got probably didn't say "...where line #5 raised:" did it?  It seems like the beginning of your error is missing.

Line #5, near as I can tell from your question, is:

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-  track' => true %>
```

But your error:

> TypeError: Object doesn't support this property or method

Looks like a javascript error, not a RoR error, as furthered by the first line it returns in the stack dump:

```
execjs (2.7.0) lib/execjs/external_runtime.rb:39:in exec...
```

So it's probably what you've posted as line #6 in the page:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
```

And what you need to do is change that line to:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag 'defaults', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
```

Comment: From reading around, it looks like some versions of Coffee Script are broken on Windows.  Some suggest downgrading to 1.8.0 if you are on 1.9.0, but hopefully the above fix will take care of it.

Answer (score 0):

Try these things in this order:

1. Restart your rails server
2. Disable Turbolinks (comment it out, or remove references to it entirely to eliminate this as a factor, even if it is temporary).
3. Put something within def home...like:

   ```
   def home
     @pages = Page.all
   end
   ```

   This should give you at least some idea of where things are causing issues.